# can't abbreviate in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to do an UPDATE across two tables.

```
UPDATE AGR_Admin.APIARIES_20160920_UPDATETEST sde
JOIN AGR_Admin.APIARIESTEMPFROMPLANTS plants ON sde.LocationID = plants.LocationID
SET sde.Longtitude = plants.Longtitude
WHERE sde.LocationID = plants.LocationID
AND sde.OBJECTID = 1;
```

I'm getting:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near 'sde'.

What the what? Why is the abbreviation a problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: what database ? This works in MySql.

Comment: The where predicate here is completely redundant. The join already specified those two values will be the same, doing it again in the where clause is overkill.

Answer (score 3):

Based on error message,i believe it is sql server

Modify your query like below

```
UPDATE sde
set sde.Longtitude=plants.Longtitude
from
AGR_Admin.APIARIES_20160920_UPDATETEST sde
join AGR_Admin.APIARIESTEMPFROMPLANTS plants ON sde.LocationID=plants.LocationID
WHERE sde.LocationID=plants.LocationID
AND sde.OBJECTID=1;
```

You are not using right syntax ,that's it..Below is syntax

```
UPDATE   
       { { table_alias | <object> | rowset_function_limited   
        }  
      | @table_variable      
    }
```

You are using Join

Answer (score 0):

If Database is SQL Server : Use this

```
UPDATE  sde
set sde.Longtitude=plants.Longtitude
FROM AGR_Admin.APIARIES_20160920_UPDATETEST sde
join AGR_Admin.APIARIESTEMPFROMPLANTS plants ON  sde.LocationID=plants.LocationID
WHERE sde.LocationID=plants.LocationID
AND sde.OBJECTID=1;
```